# Validate username/password from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-identity

The current authorization is implemented as:

1. The Single Page Application (SPA) developed in react.js, posts username/password from the Login page to Web API and waits for the authentication token.
2. The Web API doesn't implement a standard identity provider, the username/password is validated from LDAP if the user is valid it creates an encrypted authentication token, saves it in the database, and returns back to SPA.
3. The SPA once gets the token then moves to the home page and further makes all calls by using the authentication token.
4. The Web Api validates the token first for each call, if it is valid then proceeds otherwise rejects as an unauthorized user.

All this is working fine but now we have got a requirement where we have to use the Azure Active Directory along with LDAP. Is there any way that the Web API validates the username/password from AAD, and if valid then creates the same token as creating now and returns back to SPA?

Please help me in this scenario.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You got 3 solutions.

1. [OAuth Resource Password Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) - This solution comes with a lot of limitations, like no support for MFA, and no support for authenticator apps.
2. [Azure Active Directory Domain Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/active-directory-ds). (Pretty much a managed Active Directory that is a mirror of your Azure AD, and supports LDAP)
3. The correct solution, using OpenID Connect/SAML/OAuth2